# How to get sum of a UNION ALL

Tags: php, mysql

How to get sum of all rows in a `UNION ALL` query. I am trying to get sum a column of every UNION table, And Sum of result after query execution.

```
$select = $db->prepare("SELECT SUM(money) AS cash FROM table1 WHERE money > 0 GROUP BY id 
                        UNION ALL 
                        SELECT SUM(payment) AS cash FROM table2 WHERE payment > 0 GROUP BY id
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT SUM(pay) AS cash FROM table3 WHERE pay > 0 GROUP BY id 
                        ");

        $select ->execute();
        for($i=0; 
            $rows = $select ->fetch(); 
            $i++){
        $result = $rows['sum(cash)'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution with only mysql could be the following, which returns a single value of the summation of all three columns in the tables:

```
SELECT SUM(pt.psum) AS tsum FROM 
(SELECT SUM(money) AS psum FROM table1 WHERE money > 0 GROUP BY id
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(payment) AS psum FROM table2 WHERE money > 0 GROUP BY id
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(pay) AS psum FROM table3 WHERE money > 0 GROUP BY id) pt
```

For clarity,

- psum: partial sum
- pt: partial sum table
- tsum: total sum